# Checking each node in a tree structure, Umbraco (improving efficiency)

Tags: c#, algorithm, foreach, umbraco

I'm writing some C#(.NET) to work with Umbraco 4.7 to import articles into a blog. In short, this algorithm is designed to cycle through every existing article and check whether it has the same ID as the new article that we're attempting to pull in from an XML. The algorithm works alright, but I can't help but think having four foreach loops is incredibly inefficient for what I'm doing.

```
foreach (Document yearNode in node.Children) //News > Years
{
    foreach (Document monthNode in yearNode.Children) //Years > Months
    {
        foreach (Document dayNode in monthNode.Children) //Months > Days
        {
            foreach (Document newsItem in dayNode.Children) //Days > Articles
            {
                // If there isn't an ID match, go ahead and create a new article node.         
            }
```

That's the basic algorithm without it's main functionality, just the foreach loops. It's a little more complicated than simply cycling through calendar dates because it's more of a folder structure containing specific nodes. Would anyone be able to suggest a way of simplifying this at all?

Comment: Is the `Document` type above an Umbraco-specific type?

Comment: It is, yes. Part of the BusinessLogic, [link](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/creating-a-document)

Comment: Any chance you could build up a cache of the document folder structure, and perform quick lookups in the cache?

Comment: How do you retrieve the root-node (`node`)? Maybe you could query the leaf-nodes through their `DocumentType`?

Comment: Thanks for that, @MarkusJarderot, but could you explain what you mean a little more? First time with Umbraco and C#, and it feels like everything is a node!

Comment: Never used it either. I found this while browsing the documentation site: http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/enumerating-documents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the idea of getting all of your article node's by `DocumentType`, you could use an equivalent of [this GetDescendants extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8360342/1110395) to iterate through the nodes of a specific document type.

That method is written specifically for NodeFactory's `Node` class but can easily be rewritten for `Document`. To use an extension method, you'll need to create a new class and make it static. Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web;

namespace Example
{
    static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Document> GetDescendants(this Document document)
        {
            foreach (Document child in document.Children)
            {
                yield return child;

                foreach (Document grandChild in child.GetDescendants())
                {
                    yield return grandChild;
                }
            }
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

And then to use the method in our context:

```
var myDocuments = new Document(folderId)
    .GetDescendants()
    .Cast<Document>()
    .Where(d => d.ContentType.Alias == "myDocumentType");

if (myDocuments.Any(d => d.Id == myId))
{
    ...
}
```

*Note: I'm not sure why, but it seems that an `.OfType<Document>()` or `.Cast<Document>()` is required after `.GetDescendants()`. (**See edit below**)*

It would be more efficient to use NodeFactory's `Node` as opposed to `Document` since NodeFactory pulls it's information from the XML cache and doesn't make calls to the database each time like `Document` does. The only drawback to using NodeFactory is that it only contains those nodes that have been published, but usually you'll only want to work with those anyway. See [Difference between Node and Document](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/difference-between-node-and-document).

**Edit:** After doing a little of tinkering, I discovered that `Document` already includes a `GetDescendants()` method and that returns an `IEnumerable` and that's why we have to do the `.Cast<Document>()`. So it looks like you can avoid having to create an extension method if you choose to still use `Document`. Otherwise, should you still want to use something like the above extension method, you'll need to rename it to something else.

Comment: +1 Another sterling answer from dludlow. Nice work, keep it up.