# How to work with DynamicNode in Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I see some examples about DynamicNode's in Umbraco. But i don't see how i can use these.

Can anyone tell me which reference do i have to make to be able to use DynamicNode?

I'm using C#, ASP.NET webforms and Umbraco 4.7.

Comment: Sorry, i was to quick posting this question. I needed to reference umbraco.MacroEngines, and that's all.

Comment: Good, I'm glad you figured it out. Post your comment as an answer and mark it answered. You'll mainly only use `DynamicNode` for `macroScripts` in Umbraco. Any coding against the api should typically use NodeFactory's standard `Node`.

Comment: I was quite happy to find this DynamicNode, because it seems to me that this is my only option to recursively find all childnodes of a specific type, starting at a specific node. (By querying the .Descendants property)

Comment: You should check out [uQuery](http://ucomponents.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=uQuery). Also, here's a good topic about [getting descendents with Node](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019205/umbraco-4-6-how-to-get-all-nodes-by-doctype-in-c).

Comment: Is there a nice way to do what i want with uQuery? I have seen the  recursive option in the like you passed me, but it seems to me then that querying DynamicNode.Descendants with LINQ works much better..

Comment: Well, use whatever tool works best for you, but uQuery does have a `GetNodesByType(string)` method that returns a `List<Node>`. It also has a handful of extension methods for `Node` like `GetDescendantNodes()` which returns an `IEnumerable<Node>`.

Comment: I didn't know about that extension. Thanks! It does exactly what i need, without the need for those DynamicNode's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at:

[Razor DynamicNode Cheat Sheet](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/razor-dynamicnode-cheat-sheet)

You can see the references (using) at the bottom right of the page:

```
@using umbraco.MacroEngines
@inherits umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeContex
```

pehaps you need to add uComponents library (part of it it's now on umbraco core, but I think it's from 4.8.0 on).