# umbraco - how to get all of nodes by Document Type

Tags: umbraco

How can I get all nodes by specific `Document Type`?

For example, I want to get in code behind all of nodes with `Document Type: s3Article`. How can I do this?

---

New informations:

```
    IEnumerable<Node> nodes = uQuery.GetNodesByType("s3Article").Where(x => x.NiceUrl.Contains("en"));

    lvArticles.DataSource = nodes;
    lvArticles.DataBind();
```

This is my code. I had to use `Where(x => x.NiceUrl.Contains("en"))`, because I have 2 language version- without `Where` I receive nodes from all catalogues with doctype `s3Article`, but I want to get only from one language version.

Problem is here:

```
<a href='<%# umbraco.library.NiceUrl(Tools.NumericTools.tryParseInt( Eval("id"))) %>'><%# Eval("title")%></a>
<%# Tools.TextTools.makeIMGHTML("../.."+ Eval("img").ToString(),"180") %>
<%# umbraco.library.StripHtml(Limit(Eval("Article"), 1000))%>
<%# Eval("author")%>
```

> System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding:
>   'umbraco.presentation.nodeFactory.Node' does not contain a property named 'title'.

The same problem happens with the title, img, article, author. Only ID works nice. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [uQuery](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/) [`GetNodesByType(string or int)`](http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Querying/uQuery/Content/Nodes#GetNodesByType%28stringorint%29) method:

```
IEnumerable<Node> nodes = uQuery.GetNodesByType("s3Article");
```

Alternatively, you can use an extension method to get all descendant nodes and then query them by type as in the following answer:

[Umbraco 4.6+ - How to get all nodes by doctype in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8360342/1110395)

---

You could use this to databind to a control within a usercontrol like so:

```
lvArticles.DataSource = nodes.Select(n => new {
    ID: n.Id,
    Title: n.GetProperty("title").Value,
    Author: n.GetProperty("author").Value,
    Article: n.GetProperty("article").Value,
    Image: n.GetProperty("img").Value,
});
lvArticles.DataBind();
```

Only you would need to strip the html, convert the image id to a url, etc. within the select statement as well...

Comment: i'm using umbraco 4.6.2, uquery is in 4.8.. Is there any other solution?

Comment: You can use uComponents 3 for older versions of Umbraco: http://ucomponents.codeplex.com

Comment: @whoah, Jonathan is correct, uQuery was originally part of uComponents. It was integrated into Umbraco in 4.8+, but is still available as part of the uComponents package for versions prior to 4.8.

Comment: great! thanks for info about uComponents and uQuery. I add some new informations in my first post, please look at it. Regards!

Comment: I can't edit: question is- how can I get main content and tilte of this nodes?

Comment: @whoah, I've updated my answer. You might consider asking a completely separate question rather than piggy backing on another in the future.

Answer (score 2):

As Shannon Deminick mentions, uQuery is somewhat obsolete. ExamineManager will be the fastest execution time. https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/45777-uQuery-vs-Examine-vs-IPublishedContent-for-Querying

I also found it to be the easiest and most readable approach to use ExamineManager's search builder. Very flexible, and has the added benefit of being very readable due to the Fluent Builder pattern the U Team used.

This will search ALL nodes, so if you need within a specific branch, you can use .ParentId(1234) etc.

```
var query = ExamineManager.Instance.CreateSearchCriteria()
                          .NodeTypeAlias("yourDocumentType")
                          .Compile();

IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> myNodes = Umbraco.TypedSearch(query);
```

I prefer typed nodes, but you can also just use "Search()" instead of "TypedSearch()" if you prefer dynamic nodes.

Another example including a specific property value "myPropValue" == "ABC",

```
var query = ExamineManager.Instance.CreateSearchCriteria()
                    .NodeTypeAlias("yourDocumentType")
                    .Or() //Other predicate .And, .Not etc. 
                    .Field("myPropValue", "ABC")
                    .Compile();
```

Ref - https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/querying/umbracohelper/